# Enviroment variable in htaccess rewrite rule is not set

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When using the following entries in my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
SetEnv rewritten 0
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/|$) /#$1 [L,NE,R=302,E=rewritten:1]
```

Which rewrites `<url>/test/` to `<url>/#test`.

The goal is to keep the "test" part in an environment variable, so I can use php to change the Facebook metatags and also use the anchor to scroll to a section on my one-page-site. For the above example, the `rewritten` variable is always `0` and if I remove the `SetEnv` line, the variable will not be set at all.

I have read that the variable might not be retained after a redirect which the `302` will do. Is there any other way to do this? Other solutions are welcome - my overall goal is to link to a specific part of my application and set the metatags according to this section.

There are multiple questions here on SO where people try to rewrite an url with the anchor part, to an url without it - this is not my question, since it can't be done.

Thanks.

**Edit**
The above is not possible. Added the following to `.htaccess`, which redirect `<url>/test` to `<url>/?test#test`. PHP can then check if the `test` param is set and modify meta-tags accordingly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/|$) /?$1#$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Env variable can not be set using an external redirection because when the path changes Env variable also gets lost. I don't think what you want to achive is possible that way.

Comment: @starkeen You are correct. I solved it by also adding a param to the url, after the redirected. `<url>/test/` now points to `<url>/?test#test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above is not possible. Added the following to `.htaccess`, which redirect `<url>/test` to `<url>/?test#test`. PHP can then check if the `test` param is set and modify meta-tags accordingly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/|$) /?$1#$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```